# Error 1004 Looping through range to get max date

Tags: excel, for-loop, error-handling, range

I am currently learning VBA and cant figure this one out. I'm trying to look at the max date in a range (W:AC) of each row and place the result in cell "BU" of the same row. I'm getting a 1004 error on the line defining which cell to place the result. Am I getting the error because I have defined the range as W:AC?

```
Sub Max_Date()
Dim MaxDate As Date
Dim CellRange As Range
Dim Source As Worksheet: Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim row As Variant
row = Source.Rows.Count

Set CellRange = Source.Range("W:AC")


For Each row In CellRange


 MaxDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(CellRange)
 Range("BU").Value = MaxDate

Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("BU")` is not valid, it needs a row number. But your loop isn't right because it does not refer to `row` so you will get the same result every time. Also you probably don't want to loop through x million cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SJR mentioned you cannot paste a value in a row.
But also, you are looking at a max in the entire range, not only the row.
Use an integer (here i) to go through each row.

This should to the trick

```
Sub Max_Date()
Dim MaxDate As Date
Dim i As Double
Dim Source As Worksheet: Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim row As Variant
row = Source.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To row

 MaxDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Source.Range("W" & i & ":AC" & i))
 Range("BU" & i).Value = MaxDate

Next

End Sub
```